# Posts/comments - page number, Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I would like to implement [something like this](http://imageshack.us/a/img801/7226/8x0u.png) into my theme for blog posts and comments. Is there any tutorial about that ? Don't know how to name it in google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called pagination. Most themes will do it for you automatically. If you want to implement it yourself, here is a great place to start: http://www.kriesi.at/archives/how-to-build-a-wordpress-post-pagination-without-plugin

Answer (score 0):

You will want to look into the WordPress API function [`paginate_links`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links), which is intended for exactly that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin available in wordpress to do this

it is very simple to use, no need of code to write, just follow the installation steps, you will achieve it

Wordpress [wp-paginate](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-paginate/) plugin